# Apache drill parallel query is done sequentially

Tags: rest, apache-drill

I tested apache drill in local file system. 
I used rest api to query some parquet files. when i run a rest query i can not execute another query and it waits until first query finishes. i want two queries use half of cpu. but it seems multiple queries are finishing sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is regression, which is present in 1.13 and 1.14 versions:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6693

It is resolved for now. The fix is in master branch and will be a part of upcoming Drill 1.15 version.

Comment: as a matter of fact I thick, rest api has a lock that does notallow two queries at a time. So I switch to ODBC or JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Under apache drill options in the UI, check the following options:

```
exec.queue.enable
exec.queue.large
exec.queue.small
```

Description:

```
exec.queue.enable: Changes the state of query queues. False allows unlimited concurrent queries.
exec.queue.large: Sets the number of large queries that can run concurrently in the cluster. Range: 0-1000
exec.queue.small: Sets the number of small queries that can run concurrently in the cluster. Range: 0-1001
```

It also depends on the complexity of the query, if the query has joins it will consider it as multiple queries internetally and `exec.queue.large` should be higher.